# Uncaught ReferenceError: RegisterUserAcc is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched for this error on the net and tried every suggestion I've read, but it seems like my case is different.

I'm developing a cross-platform app, application framework 3 with intel xdk.

I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: RegisterUserAcc is not defined" on button onclick event.

Synopses of html5 code:

```
<div class="col uib_col_2 col-0_4-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                            <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_40 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">
                                    <input class="wide-control" type="text" id="acode" value="27">
                                </div>
                                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col uib_col_3 col-0_8-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                            <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_13 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">
                                    <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Cell Number" type="text" id="regcell">
                                </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_14 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">

                        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Email (e.g. someone@yrdomain.com)&quot;" type="text" id="regemail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_15 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">

                        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="regusername">
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_16 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">

                        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" id="regpassword">
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_17 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/input" data-ver="2">

                        <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" id="regconfirm">
                    </div><a class="button widget uib_w_18 d-margins" data-uib="app_framework/button" data-ver="2" onclick="RegisterUserAcc()" id="uib_w_18">Create Account</a>
                </div>
```

JavaScript in header has this functions:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
        };
        function LookUpUsers(usernames){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            data: Username:usernames,
                            url: "http://localhost:55288/ServiceAPIServer.svc/LookupUser",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            processdata: true, 
                            success: function(nuser) {
                            if(nuser=="" || nuser==null){return true;}else{return false;}
                            },
             });
        };

        function RegisterUserAcc(){


           var reguser=document.getElementById("regusername").value;
           alert("lookup user")
           var UsernameAvailable =LookUpUsers(reguser);
            alert("lookup user succeded, now analising data")
            if (UsernameAvailable==false){alert("Username not available, try another one."); return false;}
           var regpass=document.getElementById("regpassword").value; 
           var regconfirms=document.getElementById("regconfirm").value;
           var regemails=document.getElementById("regemail").value;
           var regcel=document.getElementById("regcell").value;
            var reglat
            var reglon
            var reggetLocation = function()
            {
                var regsuc = function(regp){
                alert("geolocation success");
                if (regp.coords.latitude != undefined)
                {
                reglat = regp.coords.latitude;
                reglon = regp.coords.longitude;
                }

                };
                var regfail = function(){
                alert("geolocation failed");
                reggetLocation();
                };

                intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(regsuc,regfail);
            }
           var regdc= new Date();
            var regimei=intel.xdk.device.uuid;
            var regip
            var regll=regdc;
            var reglocd=regdc;
             $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "http://localhost:55288/ServiceAPIServer.svc/GetRequestIp",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            processdata: true, 
                            success: function(regmyip) {
                            regip=regmyip;
                            },
             });


            if (reguser==null || reguser=="",regpass==null || regpass=="",regconfirms==null || regconfirms=="",regemails==null || regemails=="",regcel==null || regcel==""){
                alert("All fields are compulsory");
            return false;} else {
                    if(regconfirms!=regpass){alert("Passwords do no match");
                                      return false;}
                }
            if (validateEmail(regemails)){}else{alert("Invalid e-mail address"); return false;}
            if (regpass.length<6){alert("Password must be 6 characters or more"); return false;}

            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost:55288/ServiceAPIServer.svc/CreateUser",
                            data: JSON.stringify({Cell:regcel,DateCreated:regdc,Email:regemails,IMEI1:regimei,Ip1:regip,LastLogin:regll,Lat1:reglat,Loc1Date:reglocd,Lon1:reglon,Password:regpass,Username:reguser}),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            processdata: true, 
                            success: function() {
                             intel.xdk.cache.setCookie("UserId",reguser,366)
                             activate_page("#Ad");
                            },

                        });
        }
```

Comment: Do you not get any other errors in the console? You have a syntax error in `LookUpUsers()`. Fix that and retest.

Comment: Please format your code for heaven's sake.

Comment: This error means that RegisterUserAcc is not defined. Since your code is formatted so poorly, it's impossible to tell, but perhaps it's *inside* the other function? JS will not be able to "see" an internal nested function.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I fixed it but error still persists. I also realized that my other functions that worked before now gives the same error.

Comment: @torazaburo, The function is not within another function, and I don't have (document).ready(function() anywhere in the script. Something might have happened because even my other functions within the same script are no-longer working.

Comment: If you've fixed the error then [edit] your post to show the current code. (Running it through [a JS beautifing tool](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/) first wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on the line 8:   data: Username:usernames,

It should be data: {Username: usernames},   or something like that

Comment: also, check out your reguser=="",regpass==null conditions, the comma operator only returns the last expression, it's not a || "or".

Answer (score 0):

One parenthesis in the script was not closed, closing it fixed the problem. Thanks for your inputs, they helped me fix other bugs in my code.